# Composition of compositions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I am learning Haskell recently, and I was reading Functors in Learn You a Haskell from which I came to know

1. Functions `((->)r)` which take one parameter, are also in a way Functors.
2. Composition `(.)` is equivalent to `fmap`

So with what I have understood, fmap takes two parameters. First is the function to be applied, and the second one is the functor.

However, I am confused with this expression `(.) (.) (.)`. This is a composition of two composition, with the type `(b -> c) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> (a1 -> a2 -> c)`

So here is my doubt arising. The first `(.)` has two parameters, first one being composition function itself. The second parameter also being the composition function. And composition function as such is not a functor. So how is this a valid expression?

I am sure that I am missing something here. Could someone fill in the gaps and help me get how the expression is correct?

Comment: There's some confusion here. A function is a value, while a functor is a type-level object which maps types to types. The application `(.)(.)(.)` can be understood without thinking about functors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignore the `Functor` instance for `((->) r)`; it is irrelevant. Only two tings matter here: The type of `(.)`, namely

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

, and the fact that function application is *left associative*. The latter means that `(.) (.) (.)` is the same as `((.) (.)) (.)`.

Let us first try to find the type of `(.) (.)` (the leftmost ones, if you will). Let us write the type of the first `(.)` as `(b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1` and the second as `(b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2`. We apply the first to the second, which gives us that `b1` is `(b2 -> c2)` and `c1` is `(a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2`. Thus we have

```
(.) (.) :: (a1 -> (b2 -> c2)) -> a1 -> ((a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2)
```

which can be simplified to

```
(.) (.) :: (a1 -> b2 -> c2) -> a1 -> (a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2
```

Let's now apply this to to the last `(.)` (the rightmost one, if you will). If it has signature `(b3 -> c3) -> (a3 -> b3) -> a3 -> c3`, then we see that `a1` must be `(b3 -> c3)`, `b2` must be `(a3 -> b3)` and `c2` must be `a3 -> c3`. Thus,

```
((.) (.)) (.) :: (b3 -> c3) -> (a2 -> (a3 -> b3)) -> a2 -> a3 -> c3
```

which is the same as

```
((.) (.)) (.) :: (b3 -> c3) -> (a2 -> a3 -> b3) -> (a2 -> a3 -> c3)
```

This is the same as what you have in your question if you do some renaming.